# Do different types of meat fill more hunger bars?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that in Minecraft there are different types of meat (beef, pork, chicken). Do the different types of meat heal more hunger bars? This would be useful so I know what animals to kill for food.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beef (steak) and Porkchops are the best meat- each restores 8 food and 12.8 saturation. Since Cows also drop leather and can be milked, and are also easier to breed because they eat wheat, they are usually a better choice for farming.

Mutton restores 6 hunger and 9.6 saturation, making sheep a slightly worse choice for food. If you want wool from sheep, sheering them is better than killing them.

Chicken restores 6 hunger but only 7.2 saturation. It also must be cooked before eating or it may give you food poisoning. Chickens are, however necessary for feathers and eggs do allow options (infinite egg machine) that mammals don't.

Rabbit is the worst meat, restoring only 5 hunger and 6 saturation. It can be used to make Rabbit Stew- an extremely effective food- but this requires mushroom, carrot & potato.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Food#Foods

Comment: You forgot Rabbit meat (5 hunger, 6 saturation). Also, I suggest linking to the wikis food page: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Food#Foods

Comment: @MrLemon This would also be the case for Fish, as the cooked variant for fish has the same stats as cooked rabbit. However, in terms of their raw forms, rabbit would be the more wholesome choice than fish.

Comment: @Texenox I don't consider fish to be meat in Minecraft, since fish don't exist as mobs in the same way animals do.

Comment: Good point, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, different meats have diffrent amounts of hunger bars.
I suggest cows because they are easy to breed, though they are pretty loud lol.
pigs are a little harder but if your just killing them go right ahead its one of the better choices to waste your durability on,
but durability wise chickens are easier because they have very low health.

Comment: I heard that any weapon can one-shot it. Is that true (if you're using a sword)?

Comment: Chickens have the benefit of automation though. You can use a hopper to catch eggs drops and a dispenser to create more chickens from those eggs. Then use a hopper and grinder of your preference for never ending meatstacks.